# Active authentication against Azure AD

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Earlier we have ADFS based Active Authentication enabled for our client using AD.

We achieved active authentication via following curl command:

curl https://server.com/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed --data @request.txt -H "Content-Type:application/soap+xml"  --verbose -o "output.txt".

Here is my request.txt file

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
            xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
            xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
            >
                <s:Header>
                    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue</a:Action>
                    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://server.com/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed</a:To>
                    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                        <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                            <u:Created>2019-10-09T13:29:54Z</u:Created>
                            <u:Expires>2019-10-09T13:30:54Z</u:Expires>
                        </u:Timestamp>
                        <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-6a13a244-dac6-42c1-84c5-cbb345b0c4c4-1">
                            <o:Username>' . $user_name . '</o:Username>
                            <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"><![CDATA[' . $password . ']]></o:Password>
                        </o:UsernameToken>
                    </o:Security>
                </s:Header>
                <s:Body>
                    <trust:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
                        <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                            <a:EndpointReference>
                                <a:Address>https://server.com/adfs/ls</a:Address>
                            </a:EndpointReference>
                        </wsp:AppliesTo>
                        <trust:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
                        <trust:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</trust:RequestType>
                        <trust:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion</trust:TokenType>
                    </trust:RequestSecurityToken>
                </s:Body>
            </s:Envelope>
```

Now I want to achieve Active Authentication similarly on Azure AD and I want to know the method for equivalent approach.

Can someone throw a light on this?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most similar flow would be the OAuth ROPC flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc.

I would recommend that you don't use it, unless you are migrating a legacy app. 
Instead, you should use one of these flows if possible:

- Authorization code flow
- Implicit flow
- Device code flow

Their advantage is that your app doesn't need to handle passwords. Also they are compatible with MFA which ROPC is not.

Comment: Man, you made our day and helped us retain our important client with us. I am thankful to you from bottom of my heart.

Comment: Good to hear 